# How do I get SQL query with join and using STUFF and FOR XML PATH be sorted correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have a master table that has one row per key and a detail table that has many rows per key with a sequence field that has a description field I need concatenated together and create one row per key.  My code does this fine but the detail data row does not have the concatenated data in the correct order.  The data is delivered to me in an Excel spreadsheet and I use the Import Wizard to add the data to the database.  Since the order is not correct in the detail data I added a sub select to sort the data by key and sequence number that is the input into the STUFF WITH XML PATH.  I am still getting the data in an incorrect order.  If I sort the data in the spreadsheet first and then load it to the database it works fine.  I really need this to work dynamically as I want to distribute this to my team and we can use it for different tables.  Any ideas on why the sub select with the STUFF FOR XML PATH is not working?  How can I do what I need?

Here is the code I have:

```
SELECT pic, pisc, piin
    , STUFF((SELECT ' ' + P.PIIDTA FROM PI115AP P
    Where P.PIC =B.PIC
    and P.PISC = B.PISC
    and P.PIIN = B.PIIN FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') As CombinedDetail
    From 
    ( select TOP 100 PERCENT
        pic, pisc, piin, piisn, piidta
     from PI115AP
    order by pic, pisc, piin, piisn) B
    Group By B.PIC, B.pisc, B.piin
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show what is your query giving you currently and what is your expected output.

Comment: #TheGameiswar - The issue only happens when there are rows in between the sequential rows.  The detail data is over 15,000 rows and I and the

Comment: Sorry #TheGameiswar - The issue only happens when there are rows in between the sequential rows.  For example I can have
200 072 00002 1 PERM. PRESS; 7 UNBREAKABLE BUTTON
e01 006 00003 1 SOME TEXT
more rows...
200 072 00002 2 FRONT; TWO POCKETS, ONE FALSE &
more rows
The combined data will have seq 3, seq1, seq5, ordered like that.  The resulst should be seq 1 data, seq2 data, so on.  I have limited space on an add comment so I have condensed this, I hop it makes sense.

Comment: Can you please provide test scripts to create and load tables used along with the current and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of pieces and parts out of place for this to work the way you want it to. Your FOR XML is not in the order you want because the subquery has no order by. The actual result set is not in the order you want either because the main query does not have an order by. I don't really understand the point of the B subquery. The top does NOT order the actual results when using top, it just defines which rows to retrieve.

Pretty sure you want something more like this.

```
SELECT pic
    , pisc
    , piin
    , STUFF((SELECT ' ' + P.PIIDTA 
            FROM PI115AP P
            Where P.PIC = B.PIC
                and P.PISC = B.PISC
                and P.PIIN = B.PIIN 
            order by p.pic
                , p.pisc
                , p.piin
                , p.piisn
            FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') As CombinedDetail
From PI115AP B
Group By B.PIC
    , B.pisc
    , B.piin
order by b.pic
    , b.pisc
    , b.piin
```

Comment: #Sean Lange, Thanks for the reply.  I do have an order y in by sub select.  This is the sub query:

    select TOP 100 PERCENT
        pic, pisc, piin, piisn, piidta
     from PI115AP
    order by pic, pisc, piin, piisn

And your code gives me the following error:

Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 24
Column "PI115AP.PIISN" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Your subquery with STUFF does NOT have an order by. I can't actually test the query I posted because I have nothing to work with. I coded that blind.

Comment: #Sean Lange, the sub query in stuff can't have the order by because the piisn is not on the select and can't be.  I need the data concatenated to the three other fields level.

What I don't get is the sub query 
( select TOP 100 PERCENT
        pic, pisc, piin, piisn, piidta
     from PI115AP
    order by pic, pisc, piin, piisn)
returns the data in the correct order.  I though this was the feed to the STUFF query but the STUFF is not putting it in the correct order.

Comment: No that doesn't return those results in that order. select * from (select top 100 percent * from table order by)x. The order by only determines which rows will be present. If the rows are in that order it is by accident. The ONLY way to ensure order is in the final query which you do not have. And if you want the order of your STUFF in a certain way you MUST order that query also. Just try adding the order by inside the subquery being used for stuff. That is the crux of the issue you have.

Comment: I am still confused on how you can say an order by does return the data in order.  Isn't that the purpose of an order by clause?  We use order by all the time in select statements to get the data in the order we want.  I'm also confused by if the table is in sorted order this works fine but if I sort in a sub query it does not.

Comment: Is there another way to do what I need to?

Comment: What you are seeing when you order the subquery is a by-product of how the query engine works. Keep in mind that your query with the order by is a subquery, not the main query. Most of the time it will return those results in the order of the subquery but it is not guaranteed to do that. And tables do NOT have an order. By definition they are unordered sets.

Comment: I also removed the last column in the order by on my query posted above. See if that doesn't get you what you need.

Comment: #Sean Lange - YOU ARE THE MAN!  Thank you so much, that worked.  Thanks for all the informations as weel!